# What is the correct term for labeling tables in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-alias

I'm trying to figure out the correct name for table labeling.

```
SELECT var1, var2 FROM myTable TableRef
```

The label I'm referring to is the variable **TableRef**, which can be referenced from a WHERE clause like follows:

```
WHERE TableRef.var1 = 'someValue'
```

Comment: no general naming convention exists, it depends particularly on company standards

Comment: The specific term is "table alias".  This is to distinguish it from a "column alias".  When you use it with a column (`TableRef.var1`) you are *qualifying* the column name.

Comment: Your statement about referencing the label in the where clause is not correct in the example you gave.  About that delete statement, it's probably possible but it's always a good idea to do a similar select query first so that you can verify that the rows about to be deleted are the ones you want deleted.

Comment: Our company prefixes our tables with "tbl" and our views with "vw". I'm not saying its the right thing to do but it does help to know what you are selecting

Comment: @Bobby why does it matter if you're selecting from a table or a view? If you need to differentiate, I would say put the prefix on the view, but there is no good reason to prefix every table with `tbl`. Do you also put `usp_` in front of every stored procedure? Why? What are you going to confuse a stored procedure with?

Comment: I recommend using `FROM dbo.myTable AS TableRef`. (1) [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx) (2) the AS makes the intent clearer and makes it unambiguous that it isn't a hint of some kind.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Are you mad? We use "sp" not "usp_". I'm just following our standards

Comment: @Bobby http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, I never knew any of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yosi pointed out. The term I was looking for was **table alias**.