# Structured Query Language

Tags: sql

Please explain some of these SQL code snippets to me:

```
select S.sid 
from Student S
```

I don't know what the word "S" means after table name `Student`. Please give me a hand and explain.

Comment: "S" is called a table alias.  It is an abbreviation for the reference to the table.  In some circumstances they are required (say for self-joins).  In general, I strongly recommend using table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name (as in your case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037481/what-is-the-correct-term-for-labeling-tables-in-a-query

Answer (score 3):

S is an alias. `Student S`.

If you didn't specify an Alias, you could use:
`select sid from Student`
or `select Student.sid from Student`

The alias can be pretty much anything. E.G:

```
select aliasnameishere232fsdf.sid from Student aliasnameishere232fsdf
```

Alias's not only make query's easier to type, but can be useful for self-joins, for differentiation:

```
select S1.firstName, S2.firstName 
from Student S1 
JOIN Student S2 ON S2.someId = S1.someId
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1):

`S` is an alias. It's a shorter name given to `Student` in this query to make it easier to address.

It isn't very helpful in this particular query, but in longer and more complex queries, this technique really helps writing manageable code.